# Restart server and solr undefined field subtitle

Tags: java, ubuntu, solr

Was just restarted the machine due to instance password reset, the solr turn out to be unable to function properly. The server was created by previous developer and it was fine before restart. What's the possible issue?

```html
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field subtitle
 at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1292)
 at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1244)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getWildcardQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:1189)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:779)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:421)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:278)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:222)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:282)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:162)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:131)
 at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:254)
 at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:49)
 at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:169)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:160)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:269)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can see the field "subtitle" in the admin panel of solr but not in analysis. is this normal?

[image: subtitle in schema browser]
[image: subtitle not in analysis]

Comment: Well, there's a field referenced named `subtitle` that isn't defined any longer. Why it isn't defined, or why it was defined before and isn't now, depends on what your use cases is. Do you expect there to be a field named `subtitle`? Are there warming queries that expect the field `subtitle` to be there? Is it the default search field? Are you searching against the `subtitle` field? (the field name definition is your own - for your own application - there are no default fields in Solr (except for a few magical ones prefixed with `_`))

Comment: Can it be possible to debug without the source code? What i have is a war file only. I'm sure no one is editing the source code. Not sure why it's no longer defined.

Comment: Start by looking at what the Solr configuration currently is and what you expect it to be (the admin interface in Solr is fine for this) - you'll have to have some idea about what data is supposed to live in Solr to be able to make any sense of this from your projects view. The schema (in older versions as `schema.xml` inside the configuration directory, in newer versions either as managed-schema or in Zookeeper) is what defines which fields are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a field in the schema page of admin panel.